# How to view output of a program started by an SSH command in linux?

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible

I am running ansible to remotely install and run programs. Ansible uses SSH to issue commands and run modules on remote systems. One of these commands  is to run a .jar file that outputs a text prompt after it is run. How can I view this output? I can see that the command issued by ansible has resulted in a running process, so I know that the jar file was started successfully, but I have no way to view its output.

Comment: ansible uses paramiko, maybe you could try to do something using that lib in python.

Comment: Can you trick `ssh`? I do not know ansible,  so suppose you are dealing with `ssh` simply, and you are interested in the ooutput of the command `command1`. Then try `ssh -t me@remote bash -c 'command1; command1'

Answer (score 0):

You need to "register" the output from the `java somefile.jar` output like so using either the `command` or `shell` module.

```
- name: print to stdout
  command: java somefile.jar
  register: java

- debug: msg="{{ java.stdout }}"

- debug: msg="{{ java.stderr }}"
```